# How to store /etc/passwd in a hash or array?

Tags: linux, perl

I would like to store the content of `/etc/passwd` in a structure, so I can update each value later on, but I can't figure out which structure to use.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

open PASSWD, "/etc/passwd";
while(<PASSWD>) {

    chomp;
    my @f = split /:/;

    print "username $f[0]\n";
    print "password $f[1]\n";
    print "uid      $f[2]\n";
    print "gid      $f[3]\n";
    print "gecos    $f[4]\n";
    print "home     $f[5]\n";
    print "shell    $f[6]\n";
    print "--------------------------\n";

}
```

I assume it should be an array of hashes, where the username is the key, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Is "Array of Hashes of Array" the way to go?

Comment: Less love for [`getpw*` and friends](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#Fetching-user-and-group-info) each year.

Comment: and i do not see any obvious reason for that. i use one of them at least once a week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store it in a hash with usernames as keys, and the split array as value:

```
my %passwd = ();

open PASSWD, "/etc/passwd";
while(<PASSWD>) {

    chomp;
    my @f = split /:/;
    @{$passwd{$f[0]}} = @f;
}
print $passwd{'Sjoerder'}[3];
```

Answer (score 12):

See [Passwd::Unix](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Passwd::Unix):

> ABSTRACT
>
> `Passwd::Unix` provides an abstract object-oriented and function interface to standard Unix files, such as `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow`, `/etc/group`. Additionaly this module provides environment to testing new software, without using system critical files in `/etc`

Answer (score 2):

The data structure you choose really depends on what you want to do with the data. If you're most interested in pulling in the data for a given user then you could just use a straight hash where keys are usernames and the value for a given key is a reference to an array of the values from /etc/passwd:

```
open PASSWD, '/etc/passwd';
my %users;
while (<PASSWD>) {
    chomp;
    next if /^\s*#/; # ignore comments
    my ($username, @details) = split /:/;
    $users{$username} = \@details;
}

# get values for user 'root'
my $values = $users{'root'};

# print root's home
print $values->[4];
```

If you want to be able to iterate over all users and pull details in a readable fashion you might choose an array of hashes, where each has represents a user and has keys for username, password, uid etc:

```
open PASSWD, '/etc/passwd';
my @users;
while (<PASSWD>) {
    chomp;
    next if /^\s*#/; # ignore comments
    my @f = split /:/;
    my %hash;
    @hash{'username','password','uid','gid','gecos','home','shell'} = @f;
    push @users, \%hash;
}
for my $user (@users) {
    print "User $user->{username} has home $user->{home}\n";
}
```

Hope this gives you some ideas!

Comment: I'd think an array-of-arrays would be a better option to iterate over the data for performance.  And then for readability and maintainability, define some "constants", rather than remembering array index numbers.  But your point is still important, we can't suggest a structure without understanding how it will be accessed.

Comment: @B Mitch: Given the size of the typical `/etc/passwd` (usually a couple dozen users (including system accounts) and only very rarely more than a couple hundred), optimizing for performance in iterating over its contents seems pointless. Optimize for readability or functionality instead.